# Adding a background image in Ruby on Rails 2 in CSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, background-image

I generated a scaffold in ruby and I want to insert a background image to every page on the site but Im not sure what the link to the image should be.

my image is  in `app/assets/images/"dep.jpg"`

this is what i have but it isnt working:

```
background-image:url('../images/dep.jpg');
}
```

Any help? thanks

Comment: try giving the exact path. Coz even the folder `/public` has `images` folder and I think its looking there instead of your path

Comment: It depends on where your file is, relative to your images directory. `../` says go one directory up from the current file location and look for an images directory. What does your directory structure look like?

Comment: my rails project folder is called ClassSchedule/apps/assets/images/dep.jpg

Comment: and where is the file containing this line: `background-image:url('../images/dep.jpg');`

Comment: in my css file located at ClassSchedule/apps/assets/stylesheets/scaffold.css

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The webserver in rails takes `public` folder as the base of the application. Hence its looking for the specific image under `/public/images/` instead of `app/assets/images/"dep.jpg"` & since its not there over there you cannot get the image. Try to put your image in `/public/images/` folder then it would work.

**Edit:** If you are using rails 3.1 then this would be different as Rails 3.1 uses the concept of asset pipeline for the assets of your application so then then path `app/assets/images/dep.jpg` would obviously work.

Comment: im kind of new to rails so im not sure where the public folder is. im just running this on localhost using rails server

Comment: `public` folder is present in root folder of your `rails` application. The hierarchical structure goes like `<yourrailsappname>/public/images`

Comment: my public folder doesnt have an images folder, should I make one or should I just put it in the public folder?

Comment: make a folder `images` & put it there so that you can have all your `image-type` files at a place.

Comment: it has to do with CSS. you have to set an attribute to `no-repeat` like that. & Please dont forget to rate my answer if it helped.

Comment: This completely bypasses Rails 3.1's new asset handling features... It works, but it requires you to keep your image in the non-default location.

Answer (score 77):

In Rails 3.1, the path will actually be `/assets/dep.jpg':

```
background-image: url(/assets/dep.jpg);
```

If you convert your scaffold.css file to a Sass file (rename to `scaffold.css.scss`) then you can use the helper:

```
background-image: image-url("dep.jpg");
```

Answer (score 11):

If your image is in `app/assets/images/dep.jpg`, then in the css file in rails you should write `background: url('/assets/dep.jpg');`

You don't have to put the image in the public folder this way.

Answer (score 2):

background: url('/assets/image_name.jpg');

This worked for me in Rails 4.0

Comment: Sound, its my first day

Comment: Cool!! Rails way it is :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use absolute path for sure:

```
background-image:url('/images/dep.jpg');
```

Comment: I was wondering since Rails takes `public` as the basefolder, dont  you think even if he does apply the absoulte path it wont work unless & until the file is reachead by the webserver by some strange tweak?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a modern version of rails (3.1 or later I believe), you can use:

```
background: url('../dep.jpg');
```

Since the css also lives in your assets folder `..` automatically refers to the assets folder.