# Error in loading the images into view in Ruby on Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, web-applications

I'm trying to load the images in a Ruby on Rails WebApp. But I'm not able to do so. How is the Assets Pipeline is used in Ruby on Rails? Suppose I'm trying to load an image as a background like: `background: #FFC000 url(image.png) repeat;` in my CSS but I'm getting problem. I've the images directory inside `app/assets/images`. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
background: #FFC000 url('/assets/image.png') repeat;
```

or if you'll use SASS:

```
background: #FFC000 url(image_path("image.png")) repeat;
```

Check this answer: [Adding a background image in Ruby on Rails 2 in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024252/adding-a-background-image-in-ruby-on-rails-in-css)

Answer (score 0):

```
background-image: url(/assets/image.png);
```